# To filter JSON object with multiple parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON data with something like this,

```
{
    applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Senior-Knowledge-Analyst-CKA/59843",
    companyname: "Boston Consultancy Group",
    created: "",
    enddate: "",
    experience: "4-6 yrs",
    jd: "",
    location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore",
    salary: "",
    skills: "cassandra",
    source: "techgig",
    startdate: "",
    timestamp: 1528959791.958316,
    title: "Senior Knowledge Analyst CKA",
    type: ""
}
```

I want to query it with multiple key values like

```
var query = {
      skills: [],
      location: ["Bengaluru/Bangalore","Pune"],
      experience: ["4-6 yrs"]
    };
```

This is the function which I sought to write, there were a few ans regarding this, but I was unable to understand them,

```
function find_in_object(my_array, my_criteria) {

    }
```

How should I write this function so that, I can implement this feature

Thanks

Edit 1:
Able to make something like this:

```
function find_in_object(my_array, my_criteria) {
        var x = my_array.map((data)=>{
          var filter=[];
          var keys = Object.keys(query);
          keys.map((imf)=>{
              if(query.imf.indexOf(data.imf)){

              }
          })
        })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: We are not here to do your homework... show us what have you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález yes absolutely, i could write 9 query with it and it would be done

Comment: But, I want something more optimal

Comment: Programming technique tip: Get something working first and worry about "optimal" after.  Stackoverflow tip:  Post something that you think ought be working (or working faster), show what it's doing and what you expect it to do.

Comment: @lara agreed, trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward and performant (in most cases) approach is to iterate the entries of the query, looking at each corresponding prop in the objects being searched.  Fail aggressively if any aspect of the query doesn't match.

There's no getting around iterating all of the input data to test for match, nor can we avoid iterating all props in the query until a mismatch.  One place to improve speed is in array.includes() (by better indexing those arrays), but I'd test this for acceptable performance first.

```js
let data = [{
    applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Senior-Knowledge-Analyst-CKA/59843",
    companyname: "Boston Consultancy Group",
    created: "",
    enddate: "",
    experience: "4-6 yrs",
    jd: "",
    location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore",
    salary: "",
    skills: "cassandra",
    source: "techgig",
    startdate: "",
    timestamp: 1528959791.958316,
    title: "Senior Knowledge Analyst CKA",
    type: ""
  },
  {
    applylink: "some other link",
    companyname: "Acme Inc",
    created: "",
    enddate: "",
    experience: "6-8 yrs",
    jd: "",
    location: "Pittsburg",
    salary: "",
    skills: "javascript",
    source: "techgig",
    startdate: "",
    timestamp: 1528959791.958316,
    title: "Senior Knowledge Analyst CKA",
    type: ""
  }
]

// matches the first job
let query1 = {
  location: ["Bengaluru/Bangalore", "Pune"],
  experience: ["4-6 yrs"]
};
// matches the second job
let query2 = {
  location: ["London", "Pittsburg"],
  experience: ["6-8 yrs"]
};
// matches neither
let query3 = {
  location: ["Bengaluru/Bangalore", "Pune"],
  experience: ["6-8 yrs"]
};



function dataMatchingQuery(data, query) {
  return data.filter(datum => datumMatchesQuery(datum, query))
}

// true if the datum's values can be found in the query arrays for every prop
function datumMatchesQuery(datum, query) {
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(query)) {
    if (!v.includes(datum[k])) return false
  }
  return true
}


console.log(dataMatchingQuery(data, query1))
console.log(dataMatchingQuery(data, query2))
console.log(dataMatchingQuery(data, query3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but really since wasn't able to able so I cut down the requirement with just one query at a time, not with an array of query